# vb.net : split string

Tags: vb.net

i have a string which contains something like this:

**hello this is an {test, example}** 
or
**hello this is an {test, example} some other text**
or
**hello this is an {test, example} some other text { test1, example1 } etc etc etc**

now is this what i want:

create a list with all the normal text and all the text between the {}

so example:

- hello this is an
- test, example

or

- hello this is an
- test, example
- some other text

and so on ( just like the first examples of how the string looks like.

how can i do this the best?

Comment: Do you want all normal text and all the text between '}'s in two separate lists?

Comment: No they have to be on the same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses a RegEx instead of the `Split` function -

```
Dim value As String = "hello this is an {test, example} some other text { test1, example1 } etc etc etc"
Dim words As List(Of String) = new List(Of String) 

' Get a collection of matches.
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, "[^\{\}]+")

For Each match As Match In matches
    words.Add(match.Captures(0).Value.Trim)
Next
```

The `words` list should now contain the required list.